# Mobile Safari Browser - Viewport issue

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile, mobile-safari

I've looked and looked and can't find a solution. Maybe mine is a little more unique. My problem right now is that my background is getting cut off on the mobile Safari browser. here is a screenshot of how it looks like:

[image]

And here is a link to my page I am working on and how it's suppose to look:
http://www2.theadamgroup.com

Here is my source code for the body and html:

```
body {
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    background-image:url(img/paper-footerbg.png);
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-repeat:repeat-x repeat-y;
}
body, html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

And here is a snippet of how my front page is coded:

```
<body>
<div style="width:100%; min-height:100%;">
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<div id="mainBox">
  <div id="mainContent">
    <div style="float:left; width:439px; padding:35px 0 0 0;">
      <p style="font-size:34px; line-height:40px; font-weight:bold; color:#009b3a; margin:0;">High-quality printing from your neighbors in Franklin</p>
      <p style="font-size:16px; line-height:22px; margin-top:7px;">The ADAM Group is a full-service printing and design company in Franklin, Tenn. Our specialty is helping businesses develop and print high-quality brochures, catalogs, calendars, books, flyers, stationery, menus, business cards and so much more.</p>
      <p style="font-size:16px; line-height:22px;">We pride ourselves on the professional, fast service we provide in our community. Franklin is our home, and helping our neighbors succeed is our business.</p>
      <p style="margin:42px 0 0 0;" align="center"><a href="#" class="learnmoreBtn"></a></p>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width:512px; margin:0 0 0 47px;"><img src="img/tag-products.png" width="512" height="401" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You say that you have done some research - but you don't provide us with any source code, CSS rules, or anything. We cannot fix your website for you, please reduce your problem into it's smallest possible form.

Comment: Sorry, I am not trying to ask anyone fix my page for me. I am just asking for help me figure out what might be causing this problem. I updated my question with some of my source code. Its cutting off my background on the right, cutting off the navigation menu and etc.

Comment: Try and set a min-width for the body to 1058px

Comment: Also add <meta name="viewport" content="width=1058px, minimum-scale=0.1, maximum-scale=2.0"> this will insure the page loads to the width of the document.

Comment: Also note this problem is visible if the user sets (even on a computer) the browser width to be less then 1058px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have confirmed the fix:
To the header.php file add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1058px, minimum-scale=0.1, maximum-scale=2.0">
```

This will make the mobile browsers set the document size to 1058px.

Then for theadamgroup.css add:

```
Body{
   min-width:1058px;
}
```

This will force the document to be bigger then the browser width if the browser width drops below 1058px and makes it scroll

Comment: That worked. thanks! Mainly, it was adding the min-width to the body that worked. It's still ideal to have the viewport in the header though. Thanks for taking the time to help!